# Non blocking SHFileOperation

Tags: winapi

`SHFileOperation` needs a valid window handle in which it performs all window messages.

I would like to use `SHFileOperation` independently from the current calling process, so I can close the process right after `SHFileOperation` has been called (and returned?!) which means I would like to "pass" it to another process or window.

I have tried the `GetDesktopWindow` handle in order to "pass" it to the explorer.

So my question is, how is it possible to call `SHFileOperation`, close the process right after the call and it's still doing the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is, how is it possible to call SHFileOperation, close the process right after the call and it's still doing the job?

It is not possible. If you kill the process then `SHFileOperation` will be stopped before completion. The only way to achieve this is to hand of the task of calling `SHFileOperation` to a different process.

Of course, you could just as well let your process remain alive until `SHFileOperation` returns. You can close any other visible UI from your process, and wait until `SHFileOperation` completes. Then exit the process.

Comment: Would it work to do a remote thread to explorer.exe with it's window handle? I just need the copy and paste procedure with GUI and be able to pass this task.

Comment: Invading explorer is surely not a good idea. What's the problem with starting a new process? The system is all set up for that. Processes are nicely isolated. There's no danger of you killing the user's shell. You don't even need to make a new executable file. Just fire off the same executable but with command line arguments that tell it how to perform the file operation.

Comment: I guess that's the only right way to do it then. I still might try using injecting a thread to explorer.exe and post an answer here later.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss Please don't inject into Explorer. Explorer may be running in a different security context from your app, resulting in a security hole (because the files are copied under the wrong context). Also, anti-malware software gets really twitchy when they see people injecting code into Explorer, since that's something that malware loves to do.

Comment: How am I suppose to transfer like 2k files (filepath string size) to the new process?

Comment: You'd have the same issue invading explorer. Pass the args as command line args.

Comment: Command line args have a limit of 32,768 chars. Not sure if explorer's copy function also has this limit...

Comment: You might need to create a temp file, or a memory mapped file. For the latter you'd need to wait until the other process at least signaled that it had extracted the data.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't like the thought of temporary files at all. I always consider file leftovers in case of a sudden terminate of the process.

Comment: No, I don't care much for them either.